# Accessing child elements, using parent defined in xml, android

Tags: android

```
<ViewFlipper android:id=@+id/flipper >
    <ListView android:id=@+id/xyz />
    <ListView android:id=@+id/pqr />
    <ListView android:id=@+id/abc />
</ViewFlipper>
```

flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);

```
   Can I access the id of child elements of flipper(xyz,pqr,abc) ? no. of child elements of flipper ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I access the id of child elements of flipper(xyz,pqr,abc) ?

Yes, you can. For example as this:

`flipper.getChildAt(index).getId()`

> no. of child elements of flipper ?

If you mean count of children then:

`flipper.getChildCount()`

Comment: Thanks , I was looking in View documentation rather than View group.